# How to get a 3 weeks calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar

How can I customize JQuery calendar so that it shows only the days up-to 3 weeks from the current date and hide other dates not within that range rather than disabling them? If it doesn't support it, can you suggest any calendars in which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function () {
     $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        maxDate: "+21D" // or use maxDate: "+3W" for 3weeks
     });
 });
```

Read [option-maxdate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/M9C2B/)**

Comment: Thanks for the response but it doesn't hide the other days. I need to hide them rather than disabling them.

Comment: @SankaD you could...you know, do some of the work yourself http://jsfiddle.net/M9C2B/1/

Comment: Thanks. I was fiddling with only JavaScript.

Comment: @SankaD There is no option in `jquery-ui`, as it can be done using `css` only like, .ui-state-disabled {display:none;}`